# Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am trying to load a dump file into a SQL Server table using `bcp.exe` but it fails to insert one row.

#### Input Data File

Content `[\\\\SERVER\INPUT_SOURCE_FILE.DAT]`:

```
COL001|||COL002|||COL003XXDATA001|||DATA002|||DATA003XXDATA004|||DATA005|||DATA006XXDATA007|||DATA008|||DATA009
```

Column Delimiter is: `|||` and row terminator is: `XX`

#### Input Table Format

[image]

#### bcp command

```
bcp.exe [MY_DB].[dbo].[MY_INPUT_TABLE] IN "\\SERVER\INPUT_SOURCE_FILE.DAT" -c -F2 -k -C ACP -t||| -rXX -U sa -P SERVER_PASSWORD -S DBSERVER\INSTANCE
```

#### bcp output

> ```
> Starting copy...
>
> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
> Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Unexpected EOF encountered
> in BCP data-file
>
> 2 rows copied.
> Network packet size (bytes): 4096
> Clock Time (ms.) Total: 16     Average : (125.00 rows per sec.)
> ```

#### Results

Rows loaded:

[image]

but this row is not inserted:

```
DATA007 | DATA008 | DATA009 |
```

Why does it only add two rows instead of three?

I have added `\r\n` at the end of the line in order to put EOF char. I have even tried using a different delimiter(`*`) but still getting the same issue. I also tried adding a final `XX`:

```
COL001|||COL002|||COL003XXDATA001|||DATA002|||DATA003XXDATA004|||DATA005|||DATA006XXDATA007|||DATA008|||DATA009XX
```

..but it did not work either.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Are you using Azure SQL Database or locally installed? What OS are you running BCP on? If I run your BCP command in Windows 10, I get `| unexpected at this time`. If I add double-quotes around the `|||` so that the command-line has `-t"|||"` it works just fine with the first content you listed. Also, your error message is from "ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server" while if I add the extra "XX" at the end, I get that error, but from "SQL Server Native Client 11.0". Also, are you 100% sure that those are the contents of that networked file? Test a local file.